# DllExport: Passing an array of arrays from Delphi to C#

Tags: c#, arrays, delphi, marshalling, dllexport

I am using RGiesecke's "Unmanaged Exports" package to create a dll from C# that can be called from a Delphi application.

Specifically, I am looking to pass an array of arrays of a struct.

What I have made work in C# is

```
public struct MyVector
{
  public float X;
  public float Y;
}

[DllExport]
public static void DoStuff([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] 
  MyVector[] vectors, int count)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Which can then be called from Delphi, doing something like this:

```
unit MyUnit
interface
type
  TVector = array[X..Y] of single;
  TVectorCollection = array of TVector;
  procedure TDoExternalStuff(const vectors : TVectorCollection; count : integer; stdcall;
  procedure DoSomeWork;

implementation

procedure DoSomeWork;
var
  vectors : array of TVector;
  fDoExternalStuff : TDoExternalStuff;
  Handle: THandle;
begin
  // omitted: create and fill vectors
  Handle := LoadLibrary('MyExport.dll');
  @fDoExternalStuff := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'DoStuff');
  fDoExternalStuff(vectors, Length(vectors)); 
end;

end.
```

However, **what I really need to do is to pass an array of array of TVector**. An array of structs that hold an array of TVector would also do. But writing

```
[DllExport]
public static void DoStuff([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] 
  MyVector[][] vectors, int count)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Does not work with Delphi

```
...
TVectorCollection = array of array of TVector;
...

procedure DoSomeWork;
var
  vectors : array of array of TVector;
  fDoExternalStuff : TDoExternalStuff;
  Handle: THandle;
begin
  // omitted: create and fill vectors
  Handle := LoadLibrary('MyExport.dll');
  @fDoExternalStuff := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'DoStuff');
  fDoExternalStuff(vectors, Length(vectors)); //external error 
end;
```

And I would also be a bit surprised if it did, since I am not specifying the length of the individual elements of the jagged array anywhere.

Is there a way for me to setup my DllExport function to be able to marshal this type of element?

Comment: Although it works to declare import the function using the dynamic array `TVectorCollection`, be careful about this. On the C# side this is treated as a raw pointer. So it's fine as you have it, but if you were to go in the opposite direction this would break down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to setup my DllExport function to be able to marshal this type of element?

No, p/invoke marshalling never descends into sub-arrays. You will have to marshal this manually.

Personally I'd pass an array of pointers to the first elements of the sub-arrays, and an array of the lengths of the sub-arrays.

On the C# side it will look like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint count);

[DllExport]
public static void DoStuff( 
    [In] 
    int arrayCount, 
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] 
    IntPtr[] arrays, 
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] 
    int[] subArrayCount, 
)
{
    MyVector[][] input = new MyVector[arrayCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
    {
        input[i] = new MyVector[subArrayCount[i]];
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(input[i], GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            CopyMemory(
                gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 
                arrays[i], 
                (uint)(subArrayCount[i]*Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyVector))
            );
        }
        finally
        {
            gch.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

It's a little messy since we can't use `Marshal.Copy` because it doesn't know about your struct. And there is []no simple built in way to copy from `IntPtr` to `IntPtr`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/493). Hence the p/invoke of `CopyMemory`. Anyway, there's many ways to skin this one, this is just my choice. Do note that I am relying on your type being blittable. If you changed the type so that it was not blittable then you'd need to use `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

On the Delphi side you can cheat a little and take advantage of the fact that a dynamic array of dynamic arrays is actually a pointer to an array of pointers to the sub-arrays. It will look like this:

```
type  
  TVectorDoubleArray = array of array of TVector;
  TIntegerArray = array of Integer;

procedure DoStuff(
  arrays: TVectorDoubleArray; 
  arrayCount: Integer;
  subArrayCount: TIntegerArray
); stdcall; external dllname;

....

procedure CallDoStuff(const arrays: TVectorDoubleArray);
var
  i: Integer;
  subArrayCount: TIntegerArray;
begin
  SetLength(subArrayCount, Length(arrays));
  for i := 0 to high(subArrayCount) do
    subArrayCount[i] := Length(arrays[i]);
  DoStuff(Length(Arrays), arrays, subArrayCount);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems like a crude solution. But if it is only possible to make a crude solution, then so be it. But how would you pass both two lists in one method call? Would you put it in a struct, and if so,  how would you marshall that one?

Comment: Either in a struct, or as two arguments. You use two arguments at the moment. Replace `int count` with `int[] subArrayCount`. Let me know if you have trouble doing this and I'll help.

Comment: @yms It's not a multi-dimensional array. It's a ragged array.

Comment: David, I am not quite sure i follow how you would do it by changing `int count` to `int[] subArrayCount`. Writing `public static void DoStuff([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] MyVector[][] vectors, int[] subArrayCount)` does not seem to help -- I still get an external error when calling from Delphi where I change the signature of the calling method from delphi to `fDoExternalStuff(vectors, subArrayCount);` I am probably misunderstanding something?

Comment: It's going to be like this: `public static void DoStuff([In] IntPtr[] vectors, [In] int[] subArrayCount)` Each element of vectors is a pointer to the first element of the subarray. Use `Marshal.Copy` to copy into a .net array.

Comment: As it happens your Delphi ragged dyn array is compatible with `IntPtr[]` in the same way as the linear array is, subject to the proviso in my comment to the question. So that saves you one job at least!

Comment: Hmm, it's quite tricky isn't it. I've added some code to flesh it out. Hope it helps.

Comment: Again, thanks for the elaborate help! 
I could not make the above code work until I changed the signature to 
`public static void DoStuff(
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] IntPtr[] arrays,
            [In] int arrayCount,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 3)] int[] subArrayCount,
            [In] int nsubArrays)`
Before I made this change, subArrayCount did not get the right size.

Comment: Also, I think you meant to write `CopyMemory(...)` instead of `Marshal.Copy(...)` inside of `CallDoStuff`. However, I could not make this work either. What I have been able to do, is to marshal to a `float[] destArray` using `Marshal.Copy`. This however requires subsequent reallocation like this 
`for (int j = 0; j < subArrayCount[i]; j++)
  input[i][j] = new TVector { X = destArray[0 + 2 * j], Y = destArray[1 + 2 * j]};`
Which, depending on the circumstances, might be a problem (In my case, although I have not stated this before, the datastructures will often be hundreds of megabytes).

Comment: re `SizeParamIndex` you are right. That's me being sloppy. You actually only need one size param. See my edit.

Comment: And yes, you are quite right about the `CopyMemory`. As you can tell, I've just written this code without compiling or testing. But I think that's OK because the main idea is to get across the concepts. You clearly know what you are doing and can write correct code.

Comment: Anyway, I've re-jigged the answer to show how CopyMemory should be called. I hope it works now!!

Comment: Good. Sorry I was a bit sloppy here.